# Does registering a signal handler for a specific signal override another registered signal?

Tags: objective-c, signals

If we register a signal such as below, does this override another registered signal handler, that is last one wins?  If so, is there a way to allow more than 1 for each signal.

```
signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope;  there can only be one signal handler per signal.

Note also the trying to do just about anything in a signal handler is impossible.  You can't make any system calls, can't really allocate memory, and can't use Objective-C.

As well, trying to catch SIGABRT is futile.  By the time that is sent, it indicates that your app is well into the weeds.   Trying to recover from such a state is rife with fragility.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: There's state we store in memory about the data being sent/received.  Occasionally, we get an unexpected byte sequence and then get off on our reads.  We were thinking that if we could log the state after it crashed and attach to crash report, it might be helpful in fixing the issue.

Comment: That is about the most reasonable use of signals, but even that is rife with fragility.  Far better would be to detect and log the unexpected byte sequence.  Better and far easier, too.

Comment: Agreed there.  That's likely what we plan on doing.  Thanks again!